# "absent in" or "absent from": word usage and prepositions

Tags: word-choice, word-usage, prepositions

> Notably, a term x is **absent in/from** Eq. (4).

After consulting Gartner and online common use, I remain confused about how to decide which the correct preposition to use should be?

For my colleague, it was self-evident that it should be "in," but perhaps someone can help explain how one could reason this?

Comment: After thinking about this for a few minutes (as a native speaker of American English), I can come up with no situations where either preposition could not be used to communicate absence. It's certainly not "self-evident" that it should be *in* and not *from* in that case, unless there is some special usage in mathematics that I'm not familiar with. If this is the case, perhaps you should ask a mathematician.

Comment: Ok, good to know. Thank you, maybe I will try that.

Comment: @Robusto, I guess your comment is an answer that should be accepted.
All of us have our own self-evident rules. It's Ok to use them but it's not enough to teach or judge one's language. Being subjective self-evidence still requires some formal support. If it lacks the former I reckon it can be safely ignored.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me try the explanation I came up with for myself:

- "absent from" would indicate "should be there but is not": the student is absent from school today.
- "absent in" would indicate "this trait / element/ etc." is not a part of something: fear of death is absent in many African religions.

Comment: You could improve your answer by providing references for the information you give. "Self-made" explanations are not very popular here.